# Debugging w/Embedded Mono how to set breakpoints in C# code?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm using Embedded Mono, its working great.  The main app is C++ and I'm able to load assemblies, construct objects, call methods, etc.

What I want to do now, is be able to use MonoDevelop to connect to my program, then be able to set breakpoints in the Managed(C#) code.  After much research, I am passing the following
to:

```
    static const char* options[] = {
          "--soft-breakpoints",
          "--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:10000"
        };

mono_jit_parse_options(sizeof(options)/sizeof(char*), (char**)options);
mono_debug_init(MONO_DEBUG_FORMAT_MONO);
```

After making the above calls, the app will connect to MonoDevelop.

On the MonoDevelop side, I set the env. `var MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST=y` which allows you to
use the "Run -> Run With -> Custom Command MonoSoft Debugger and it will connect to the
app.

Here is the tricky part: In order to have the Run With -> Custom Command MonoSoft Debugger
choice you neeed to have a project opened, to do this, I simply opened the (Debug built) assembly, then, in the Project Options I added a custom "Execute" command and pointed to the C++ .exe, and checked "Run on external Console".

After clicking "Listen" in the MonoSoft Debugger dialog, my app starts up, I see messages in the Application Output about my assemblies, however, If I open up the source file (C#) and try to set a breakpoint, the turn the disabled color and never get hit.  What am I missing, do I need to call some other mono_debug function to inform mono to debug my assemblies, is there some sort of gdb-like path property to tell MonoDevelop where to look for sources?

Comment: Forgot to mention, using Mono-2.10.8 and MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5, all on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When our app prints stack traces (Environment.Stacktrace) do they have source file and line information? If not, you should check that you have mdb symbol files beside the assemblies.

If your managed code was built with .NET's compilers, you will have pdb files, which Mono cannot load. Use the pdb2mdb tool to convert them to mdb files.

Also check that the file paths in the stack traces match the paths to the actual source files on the host machine.